# WCF extension link error in .net 6.0 and vs2022

Tags: .net, wcf

we have our own WCF extension since from netframework 4.5.2, working fine for many year, also fine with 4.8, now we start migrate it to .net 6.0, by the official doc, saying that start from .net 5.0, WCF split into two parts, CoreWCF.* for client, System.ServiceModel.* for server. but i checked through all of them, some class not found like below, suppose it should be in *.Primitives. any one has any idea?

```
The type or namespace name 'ChannelListenerBase<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `ChannelListenerBase<>` is not supported in.NET 6.0.  [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.channellistenerbase?view=netframework-4.8) states that the highest version it can support is.NET Framework 4.8.

Other classes should be used in.NET 6.0. You can refer to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-6) for .NET 6.0 new features.